Reasonable question closed far too quickly
This (admittedly elementary) question was closed far too quickly.  One commenter (and, I would guess, at least some of the close-voters) missed the point.  The OP is not overlooking the relativity of simultaneity.  In fact, the whole question is premised on the fact that events A and B are simultaneous in Frame One but not in Frame Two.  The question is:  Why, in Frame Two, does B come before A rather than vice versa?
In other words, the OP could not have asked this question without understanding that simultaneity is relative.
Moreover, she indicates that she's worked through the math, understands the math, but is lacking a good intuition.  I can easily imagine a strong beginning student in exactly that position.  This question deserves an answer and I hope it can be re-opened.

I'm one of the close voters, I have two remarks to make here: 1. By your interpretation, the OP wants to discuss frames, not observers. An observer will see the closer box exploding first, so it was unclear to me what computation OP really carried out, and whether the question is about an observer or the measurement carried out by an inertial reference frame, which as you know are different things. 2. Also please note that the first version of the question, before the latest edit, is worded quite poorly. I voted on the first version.

@Amit:  Re point 1):    Yes, this abuse of language is, for better or worse, quite common, and bad when it causes confusion, but I see no evidence that this particular poster was confused on this point.   She seems quite clearly to be saying that if A and B are simultaneous in one frame, then B occurs before A in a  certain other frame, and if I'm right about what she's saying, then she's absolutely right.  Moreover she says she's verified the math.  I think it takes a strong and curious student to wonder why the math came out this way rather than the opposite.

I agree, and if OP actually included the computation done, that would have removed any ambiguity (after all, correcting terminology is a legitimate part to be clarified as part of an answer). That's what I would expect since as you said "she's worked through the math", which I also believe, she should also show her work in the context of such a question. Nonetheless, I've just voted to reopen now.

I looked at the entire edit history of this question. IMO, the closure was warranted. The closed version was indeed unclear. The edits were good and the question was duly reopened. It seems that in this case the system worked exactly as it should

The fact that you need to explain this question means that it probably needs more clarity. The question author (or yourself, but preferably after discussing with them) could modify the question and demand its reopening - which requires the same number of votes as closure.
The rules are not perfect, since in practice reopening question is usually more difficult than closing it... but Physics is not the worst in this case - in some SE communities questions routinely go through multiple closures and reopenings, simply because people vote based on their likes/dislikes of the subject, rather than the merits of the question itself.

"The fact that you need to explain this question means that it probably needs more clarity. "  This is a good presumption most of the time, but I don't think it applies in this case.  The question started off with the observation that events A and B were simultaneous in one frame, whereas B preceded A in another.  The first comment (followed by a cascade of close votes) said, in effect "You're ignoring the relativity of simultaneity".    Clearly the commenter had not read the question.
